# Translated content is returning ??? after upgrading spring boot to 2.6.6

Tags: spring-boot

We have extended MessageTag and customized message tag library for labels and contents with Translation, and it was working before Spring boot upgrade.  After upgrading to Spring boot 2.6.6 we are getting ????? for the translated content.  We tried setting UTF-8 wherever possible still no luck.

Comment: please consider adding the code which can replicate the issue

Comment: public class abcMessageTag extends MessageTag {
  protected String resolveMessage() throws NoSuchMessageException, JspException {
     //get the labels Text from attributes  
     Map labelMap = labelsText;
     return message based on locale and code
     
  }
 }
 
 In the TLD call to abcMessageTag
 
 In the jsp we invoke <abc:message code="lbl_hp" />